# vue signature pad is not working in vue ionic

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs3, ionic5

I am trying to use vue signature pad plugin in my ionic vue app butt it is not displaying anything

```
<VueSignaturePad
      width="500px"
      height="500px"
      ref="signaturePad"
      :options="{ onBegin, onEnd }"
    />
    <div>
      <ion-button @click="save">Save</ion-button>
      <ion-button @click="undo">Undo</ion-button>
    </div>
```

```
import VueSignaturePad from 'vue-signature-pad';

 components: {
    VueSignaturePad
  },

methods: {
 undo() {
      this.$refs.signaturePad.undoSignature();
    },
    save() {
      console.log(this.$refs.signaturePad)
      const { isEmpty, data } = this.$refs.signaturePad.saveSignature();
      console.log(isEmpty);
      console.log(data);
    },
}
```

It should display signature area but not showing anything

Comment: and there is no error in console? btw. i would change the file name to `VueSignaturePad.vue` and would use the component inside my template like `<vue-signature-pad>`

Comment: no there is no error in the console. file name is already like that inside plugin